# How start , stop mongoose from windows CLI

Tags: windows, mongoose-web-server

I need to start, stop mongoose using windows cli.

I tried with sc start mongoose.exe command. But I am getting this error.

[SC] StartService: OpenService FAILED 1060:

Any body can help me please.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found start command for mongoose

> Mongoose Folder >mongoose -cgi_interpreter /full/path/to/php-cgi 
>   -listening_ports 8080,8081s -document_root C:\ProjectFolder

But still I dont know how to stop service

Answer (score 0):

For Mongoose 6.5, either you just kill the process from the Task Manager, or you go to the tray icon (blue one), right click on it and choose Exit.